# Python Syntax / REDIS

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

When using the built in redis-cli for REDIS on Linux, I can enter the following command with no issue

```
redis-cli -p 6379 mset SWSUIT "{\"D0:\": {\"install\": {\"rules\": [[0.62, -0.34], [-0.00, 4.95], [0.00, 0.00, 0.18]], \"name\": \"DO\", \"slows\": [[[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"type\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]]], \"suit\": [0, 1, 1, 1], \"test\": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}, \"pal\": [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0], \"alto\": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}"

    r.mset('SWSUIT', '"{\"D0:\": {\"install\": {\"rules\": [[0.62, -0.34], [-0.00, 4.95], [0.00, 0.00, 0.18]], \"name\": \"DO\", \"slows\": [[[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"type\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]]], \"suit\": [0, 1, 1, 1], \"test\": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}, \"pal\": [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0], \"alto\": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}"
')
```

When using redis-py in a python script to enter this value I cannot make it work. I keep getting an error saying I must insert a kwal or dictionary. I am assuming this is because python is interpreting the quotes and backslashes differently. Is there any way I can perform the command without changing the value? It must be formatted exactly as is seen above. I have also tried the os package to perform the command.

```
os.system('redis-cli -p 6379 mset SWSUIT "{\"D0:\": {\"install\": {\"rules\": [[0.62, -0.34], [-0.00, 4.95], [0.00, 0.00, 0.18]], \"name\": \"DO\", \"slows\": [[[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"type\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]]], \"suit\": [0, 1, 1, 1], \"test\": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}, \"pal\": [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0], \"alto\": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}"
```

')

Which sort of works, but enters the value into REDIS incorrectly formatted

Thank you.

Comment: you're not giving it a dictionary in any case, but rather a dictionary within a string

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about the formatting of the JSON string.  The error you are getting back is indicating that you're passing the wrong arguments to the function.  The `mset` call in `redis-py` expects either keyword arguments or a Python dictionary as input.  The [`MSET`](https://redis.io/commands/mset) command in Redis is for setting the value of multiple keys in a single action, so the Python API expects one of those two forms mapping Redis keys to their value.  If you change your code to something like:

```
myDict = { 'SWSUIT': '"{\"D0:\": {\"install\": {\"rules\": [[0.62, -0.34], [-0.00, 4.95], [0.00, 0.00, 0.18]], \"name\": \"DO\", \"slows\": [[[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"type\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]], [[{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 1, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"p\", \"order\": 2, \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}], [{\"bit\": \"c\", \"gfx\": 0, \"N\": 4}]]], \"suit\": [0, 1, 1, 1], \"test\": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}, \"pal\": [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0], \"alto\": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}"' }
r.mset(myDict)
```

You'll get the results you want.  Given that you're only trying to set a single data type, the `set` method would be a better choice.